# logins with cURL

Tags: bash, ubuntu, curl, libcurl, blackboard

I'm looking to use cURL to login to Blackboard, a course management system used a many universities. (For example, http://blackboard.unh.edu)

How would I do this? Blackboard uses HTTPS certificates and cookies too I believe. Thanks!

Comment: Do they have web service to do this task? [BBDN](http://www.edugarage.com/display/BBDN/Documentation)

Answer (score 2):

Do a view source of "https://blackboard.unh.edu/webapps/portal/frameset.jsp" and figure out what form fields are login and password.

Then use curl's --data option to POST that data. If compiled w/ SSL, curl will handle https as easily as it handles http.

A truly ugly (but easy) option: install paros proxy and set your web browser to use it. Then you can see unencrypted the traffic that you're sending to the site.

Comment: Just use the developer tools in Safari/Chrome or Firebug.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to achieve this is to install the AutoSignOn Building Block at http://projects.oscelot.org/gf/project/autosignon/.

With that B2 installed all you need to do is craft the correct URL to login to Blackboard.